# Permission to create SQL view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I've created a webapp for my thesis on my localhost. Now, when trying to import the MySQL in a live enviroment i'm denied the right to create a VIEW.

```
#1142 - CREATE VIEW command denied to user 'md122830db219181'@'172.16.0.22' for table 'x_likes'
```

Is it possible to overcome this? Or can anyone recommend another host that does allow views (real cheap, just need it to upload my thesis and it needs to be online for like a month).

Comment: What database are you using? Please specify!

Comment: The error message looks MySQL-y? This is highly RDBMS specific. Please always tag questions with the correct database: MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle etc, it'll help everyone answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on MySQL, use http://versio.nl, very cheap and I just tested views, they are allowed.